# Check whether .net 4 client profile is installed on user's machine

Tags: javascript, .net-4.0, registry, clickonce, user-agent

Similar questions have already been asked and answered in this forum, but I'm having a different query here.

I have a web page with an install button, which downloads and installs the application (clickonce) into the user's machine. I need to display a message on the web page if the user's machine is missing .Net 4 Client profile.

The options which I know are:

1. Check the user-agent string (which I guess is not recommended, as per so many experts)
2. Check registry key (which is not possible in my case, because my users may not have admin privileges in their machines, which will block the code for checking registry)

Now I guess the only option left out is, to check the user-agent string. I searched for the user-agent string of .net 4 Client profile, but didn't get it anywhere.

Please let me know if any other options are available for me, or a suitable user-agent string for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself :)

navigator.userAgent.indexOf(".NET4.0C") did the trick for me.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf(".NET4.0C") != -1)
    // .net 4.0 Client Profile exists
else
    // doesn't exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered writing a batch script that downloads with the program and in the case of installation failure reports something  along the lines of 'Unable to install. Please contact your systems administrator' or an executable that does the same thing?  It is unlikely that in a decently administered client machine with no admin privileges that you'll be able to access registry information, although there might be a .net caps program that you can run within the batch script.

Alternatively, you might consider something along the lines of silverlight or flash?

Comment: The requirement is to validate the existence of .net 4, before the user even tries to download. So I can't perform this method.